# Dropdown not working when anonymous

Tags: 7

The site I'm working on has a issue where some some drop-downs are un-clickable only when anonymous (not logged in).

It was also pointed out that it works fine on Firefox, IE and Opera, while I was using Chrome.

Has anyone else experience anything similar?

Comment: In chrome, right click and click on inspect. Select console and refresh page, do you see any errors there?

Comment: Apart from "Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired" warning, nothing else (and that warning appears when logged in too).